# PurePdf draw shape inside table cell

Tags: actionscript-3, purepdf

I'd like to draw a shape inside a table using purepdf as3 library. I haven't found any sample code on google. I think I should use a template to draw my rectangle and then add this to a cell.

```
        var template:PdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(30, 30);
        template.setLineWidth(.5);
        template.rectangle(0,0,17,17);
        template.stroke();

        cell.addElement(template);
```

Could someone give some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/wiki/Examples)
Looks like you are looking for is exemplified here [DrawingPaths](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/source/browse/examples/src/DrawingPaths.as)

Comment: I've already checked all example. The problem here is that I need a simple way to design a draw inside a table cell. In itext I do this using template. However cannot make it working using purepdf.